# android volley: Updating listview on item click

Tags: android-listview, android-volley

I want :

1. my listview to be updated when click on refreh button (action bar)
2. to be able to scroll while the update task is running.

   `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.refresh:
           setRefreshActionButtonState(true);
           this.startRequest();
       ....

       return true;
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }`

and this is how **startRequest ()** looks:

```
private void startRequest() {
    articleList.clear();
    articleList.addAll(articleList);
    //volley request
    ...
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

The first point (updating listview) is ok when I click on refresh, but how can I resolve the 2nd point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
articleList.clear();
        articleList.addAll(articleList);
        //volley request
        ...
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Do this only after you get your response successfully in you Volley's complete listener. Till then do not notify the adapter or clear the data.